# Reading Binary Data in R

Tags: r, binary, binary-data

I am trying to read binary data into R but since it's my first time doing this, I am having some problems.

This is how my binary data looks like -

[image]

and this is the structure of the data -

[image]

I started playing with the readBin function in R -

```
data <- readBin(file(file_to_read,"rb"),integer(), n = 1, endian = "little")
```

this gives me data as 3 and which looks encouraging.

Now, since only ID1 is integer and rest of the variables are real, readBin function like this -

```
data <- readBin(file(file_to_read,"rb"),integer(), n = 4, size = 4, endian = "little")
```

should (I may be wrong here) give me first four values of ID1, but I get

```
3 -2147483647   464465287  1082846778
```

How can I correctly read the data with given structure?
What I eventually want to do is to create a new data frame with two columns "ID1" and "AB_Time" from the data.

Thanks very much!

Comment: It's hard to help w/o a file. Take a look at https://github.com/hrbrmstr/swatches (there's _lots_ of `readBin` in it)

Comment: I checked in the swatches repo but really could not find readBin example. I know since you saying so it must be there but it is just that I didn't know where to look.
Is there a way I can share a sample data file to get some help?